# Force Literal ASCII character into string

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm generating the following array for use in a JS charting library:

```
[&#x27;DE&#x27;,   50], [&#x27;GB&#x27;,   9], [&#x27;IE&#x27;,   2]
```

However, I need to force in the literal apostrophe so that the JS library renders the chart correctly. i.e. ['DE',   50], ['GB',   9], ['IE',   2]

I'm sure this is simple, but I just keep ending up with the ASCII codes.

My Ruby code is

```
@product.sales_data.map { |territory,sales| "['" << territory << "',   " << sales.to_s << "]" }.join(", ")
```

Comment: Sorry it's an array, my mistake

Comment: Yeah, it works fine if it's just rendering as html but as it's being passed to some Javascript, the apostrophes are being seen as the ascii code and not the literal character it needs.

Comment: So in your code, my understanding is that you need to place into the code before sending the JavaScript this array made in Ruby to make the script, and it's showing `&#x27` in the source instead of `'`?  Am I right in saying that?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in ruby 2.0.0 at least

```
sales_data = [['DE', 50], ['GB', 9], ['IE', 2]]
sales_data.map { |territory, sales| "['" << territory << "', " << sales.to_s << "]"}.join(", ")
```

or alternatively

```
sales_data.map { |territory, sales| "['#{territory}', #{sales}]" }.join(", ")
```

Comment: I like what you've suggested on the alternative, but this is still rendering the apostrophes as the ascii code when passed to the javascript. I'm not so sure the answer lies in Ruby but in escaping these in what's rendered in the JS.

Comment: How exactly are you sending that string to js? Can you write a js function that takes in an argument and prints it out and then send your ruby string to that function to test if it is passed correctly? Also do you want to send a string or an array to that js function?

Comment: Calling .html_safe on sales_date seems to have done the trick.